# add_row and do some calculations

Tags: r, dplyr

Say I have a data.frame that looks like the below:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("group1","group1", "group2", "group2"), 
                 year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001), 
                 value = c(10, 13, 2, 5))
```

And I want to group by each group, then add a row, then do a calculation on column 3. So for example, the new data frame would look like this (the calculation was simply `value(-1)+value(-2)`)

```
df <- data.frame(group = c("group1","group1", "group1", "group2", "group2", "group2"), 
                 year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002), 
                 value = c(10, 13, 23, 2, 5, 7))
```

I've tried using dplyr, but I cant seem to figure it out. So I am open to any solution, although if there is a dplyr one that would be great!

Further, I want to be able to do this ten periods into the future so year would be the sequence from 2000 to 2011 in the final data.frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of Fibonacci-like calculation that is really simple to write with a `for` loop, and not so much with vectorized operations. `for` loops should be used with caution in R, as using them incorrectly can render your code shockingly slow, but if you preallocate memory by expanding your data.frame with `tidyr::complete` beforehand, you can code a function to contain the loop easily enough:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(group = c("group1","group1", "group2", "group2"), 
                 year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001), 
                 value = c(10, 13, 2, 5))

fibonacci <- function(x){
    for(i in seq(3, length(x))){
        x[i] <- x[i-1] + x[i-2]
    }
    x
}

df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    complete(year = 2000:2005) %>% 
    mutate(value = fibonacci(value))

df2
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>     group  year value
#>    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 group1  2000    10
#>  2 group1  2001    13
#>  3 group1  2002    23
#>  4 group1  2003    36
#>  5 group1  2004    59
#>  6 group1  2005    95
#>  7 group2  2000     2
#>  8 group2  2001     5
#>  9 group2  2002     7
#> 10 group2  2003    12
#> 11 group2  2004    19
#> 12 group2  2005    31
```

If you want to avoid the loop and vectorize, use a formulaic expressions of the Fibonacci sequence. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression),

```r
fibonacci2 <- function(u0, u1, n){
    phi <- (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2
    psi <- 1 - phi
    a <- (u1 - u0 * psi) / sqrt(5)
    b <- (u0 * phi - u1) / sqrt(5)
    a * phi^n + b * psi^n
}

df3 <- df %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    complete(year = 2000:2005) %>% 
    mutate(value = fibonacci2(value[1], value[2], seq.int(0L, length(value) - 1)))

df3
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>     group  year value
#>    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 group1  2000    10
#>  2 group1  2001    13
#>  3 group1  2002    23
#>  4 group1  2003    36
#>  5 group1  2004    59
#>  6 group1  2005    95
#>  7 group2  2000     2
#>  8 group2  2001     5
#>  9 group2  2002     7
#> 10 group2  2003    12
#> 11 group2  2004    19
#> 12 group2  2005    31
```

Somewhat curiously (likely due to proper preallocation and R's addition of JIT compilation for loops), there's little time differential between the two. Benchmarking is tricky, as the series tends exceed `.Machine$double.xmax` and turn to `Inf` at about the 1475th term, but replicated on new inputs to 1,475,000 calculations with each method,

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    fibonacci = replicate(1000, {
        x <- double(1475); 
        x[1:2] <- rnorm(2); 
        fibonacci(x)
    }),
    fibonacci2 = replicate(1000, {
        x <- double(1475); 
        x[1:2] <- rnorm(2); 
        fibonacci2(x[1], x[2], seq.int(0L, length(x) - 1L))
    })
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>   fibonacci 249.4110 255.9866 264.2625 261.6491 272.0018 295.3266   100
#>  fibonacci2 202.3588 209.0647 219.0509 214.2429 223.5476 375.7604   100
```

Comment: I used a simplified example for the calculation - the actual calculation is more complicated. It needs to use the growth in the previous period as a predictor for future values. But the complete function what has done it (plus the loop) as some parts are history and some forecast and I want to preserve history - if any of that makes sense